# CKEditor Inline Editing - Color not working

Tags: jquery, colors, ckeditor, inline, contenteditable

I seem to have a problem getting the colour options to work on the `CKEditor`.

This only happens when I'm using **inline editing** via the **contenteditable attribute**, so its not down to lack of plugins.

The options are available in my toolbar but when I click them it throws 2 javascript errors:

```
ckeditor.js:681 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined

ckeditor.js:680 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_' of undefined
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are implementing the in-line editor? Thanks.

Comment: The configuration is...

Comment: I'm just implementing the inline editor by putting contenteditable="true" on the div.

Comment: So you use both CKEditor and a separate div with contenteditable="true" on the same page? Or what? You should really be more specific: for now it's impossible to reproduce your problem, since it's not clear what code do you use and how.

Comment: I've got a page with a dynamic number of divs each having the attribute of contenteditable="true" . If they have that attribute CKEditor will automatically make them inline editable. I then loop through the editors and set a specific custom toolbar for them. The error occurs when I click on the color options. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline

Comment: Did you make any progress here? I've seen the question asked at least one other place with no answer, and I'm running into it myself as well.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved it?

Comment: I can't remember what my original code was but it was something to do with how I was setting the toolbar I think. I'm now using this code which seems to be ok. `$("div.mydiv").each(function() {
         var config = {};
         config.toolbar = "mytoolbar";
         $(this).attr("contenteditable", true);
         CKEDITOR.inline(this, config);
    });`